# Laravel 8 - PHPUnit Test problem using "Date Mutators" and Faker

Tags: testing, phpunit, faker, mutators, laravel-8

I noticed that setting a Date Mutator field in `protected dates` array into the Model, the date format used in the `Faker` are modified as `Carbon` object and do not return the format set in the `Faker`; is this normal?

To explain the problem, the Model is something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $dates = [
        'seen_at'
    ];

    // other code here...
}
```

the `Factory` class contains:

```
<?php
namespace App\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Post::class;
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'number'         => $this->faker->randomDigit,
            'seen_at'        => $this->faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP', $max = 'now'),
            'quality'        => $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-D][A-D]'),
        ];
    }
}
```

and the `Test` class is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Factories\PostFactory;

class PostControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $post = PostFactory::new()->make();
        dd($post->seen_at);

        // other code here....
    }
}
```

Runnig the Test, the `dd()` returns:

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @228109214 {#2283
  #constructedObjectId: "00000000486a8e5f00000000514b58c9"
  #localMonthsOverflow: null
  #localYearsOverflow: null
  #localStrictModeEnabled: null
  #localHumanDiffOptions: null
  #localToStringFormat: null
  #localSerializer: null
  #localMacros: null
  #localGenericMacros: null
  #localFormatFunction: null
  #localTranslator: null
  #dumpProperties: array:3 [
    0 => "date"
    1 => "timezone_type"
    2 => "timezone"
  ]
  #dumpLocale: null
  date: 1977-03-25 03:40:14.0 +00:00
}
```

the `date` do not match the format specified into the `Faker`, that should be `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP'`; but is `1977-03-25 03:40:14.0 +00:00`.

If I remove the `seen_at` from `protected $dates` array, running the test again the output is correctly:

```
"1970-02-10T03:13:34.000+00:00"
```

Another think is that if I `dd()` the entire Model generate from `Faker` with `protected $dates` that contains `seen_at`:

```
class PostControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $post = PostFactory::new()->make();
        dd($post);

        // other code here....
    }
}
```

the output it contains correct date:

```
App\Models\Post {#2399
  #table: "post"
  . . .
  #attributes: array:39 [
    "number" => 8
    "seen_at" => "1970-02-10T03:13:34.000+00:00"
    "quality" => "AB"
  ]
  . . .
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Is this behaviour normal? If "yes", how I can return the correct date format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Me and my colleague had the same issue. We worked around it like this:

```
   class PostTest extends TestCase
   {
    public function test_can_create_post() {
        $data = [
            ...//data
            'seen_at' => $this->faker->date(),
        ];

        $post = null;

        try {
            $post = Post::create($data);
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
        
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Post::class, $post);
        ...
        $this->assertEquals($data['seen_at'].' 00:00:00', $post->seen_at);
    }
}
```

And my TestCase class looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication, WithFaker;
}
```

With this configuration, the test passes successfully!!